# how can I use Count distinct function for column A and add a condition of sum for column B

Tags: reporting-services, count, sum, iif

I have a table where column A is "id" and column B is "State" as these columns are in relation ship with other table the values get repeated, but I want to calculate distinct "id" with State their which are fixed(Like deliverd, not delivered, Inprocess). But I am not able to get the count in table. Though I can do that in a chart but it needs to be shown in table.

Comment: Used following expressions and it resolved my issue   = CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!B.Value="Delivered", Fields!A.Value,Nothing))